# Junit test cases for REST API calls with lambda functions

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-webflux

Consider a REST API call method which internally uses lambda functions, how do we write the Junit test cases. I tried myself, but failed to mock the uri builder which is expressed as a lambda function in the POST API call. Also how to mock the block inside flatMap. The code snippet for which I try writing unit test is given below.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> findEmployee(String empName, String empId) {
        
        response = employeeService.post.uri(builder -> builder.path(pathMapper.get("GET_PATH")).queryParam(EMP_ID, empId).build())
            .accept(APPLICATION.JSON)
            .syncBody(empName)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap( empResponse -> {
                LOGGER.info(empResponse.getStatusCode());
                return empResponse.toEntity(String.class);
            }).block();
            
            return response;
    }
```

Where, employeeService is a Webclient object.

Answer (score 0):

Friends don't let friends mock Fluent APIs.

The lambda is embedded inline so *cannot* be individually tested. If you need that then you must extract it to a method call which *can* be tested.

```java
  .flatMap( this::handleResponse )
  .block();
...
String handleResponse( Response empResponse ) {
  LOGGER.info(empResponse.getStatusCode());
  return empResponse.toEntity(String.class);
}
```

More generally, you might want to look at something like [Wiremock](http://%20http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/) which sets up a local webserver that you can seed with set test responses.